# Programmatically uninstall a device in windows device manager

Tags: windows, winapi

Is it possible to programmatically uninstall a device in windows and perform a 'scan for hardware changes' programmatically? Is there any VB script that can be used for the same? Or is there any windows API that can be called to achieve the same?

Answer (score 4):

To force the 'scan for hardware changes' checkout "[How To Force Reenumeration of a Device Tree From an Application](https://web.archive.org/web/20140111225728/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259697)" the sample there shows how to force the entire tree to be re-enumerated.

As to removing a driver checkout [DiUninstallDevice](https://web.archive.org/web/20100327225108/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835061.aspx).

Comment: Hi Ruddy,
Thank you very much for the post. I will try out the links that you had pointed to.

Regards
Ananth

Comment: Hi,
Thank you so much for the response. I was trying to execute the program in the link, 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259697

But I found out that this requires the file cfgmgr32.lib to be included. I was unable to find that file anywhere in my SDK folders, nor in the internet.
Can you please guide me in this regard?

Regards
Ananth

Comment: @AnanthPadmanabhanCB I was able to include the Cfmgr32.lib by placing the following call in my source code: `#pragma comment(lib, "Cfgmgr32.lib")`

Comment: @Ruddy Does using the 'scan for hardware changes' code you're comment mentions cause the Device Manager->Disk Drives to show a new hard drive?  I need to get the new hard drive to trigger off a windows message like `WM_DEVICECHANGE` for most likely the event `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL`?